# Most common words in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese, topolect, hong-kong

There are many resources documenting the most common words for Mandarin, but none for Cantonese. Is there a list of the most common 500/1000/2000 words in Cantonese? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am working on some tiny SMT project at the moment and I was looking for this too, the only one I could find is this [word list](http://ec-concord.ied.edu.hk/hkcc/corpus/listword.php) from this [corpus of mid-20th century Hong Kong Cantonese](http://ec-concord.ied.edu.hk/hkcc/corpus/), It might not be great if you are using them for learning Chinese, as it's mid-20 century's.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one ::::::::::::::广东话常用语对照表 http://www.360doc.com/content/11/0228/19/4410155_96958044.shtml

Comment: Had a look at the list, purely out of curiosity...I had no idea 炒鱿鱼 was cantonese and 开OT for 加班 is pretty awesome (like: start the over time - as in start the overtime pay)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following websites:

http://www.cantonese.asia/attachments/school/canchars.htm

http://www.chinapage.com/language/suyu/gdfy/gdfymain.html

and cross-check the results with the ancient meaning of the characters by:

http://www.zdic.net/

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn Mandarin lists (of characters) into Cantonese aids by using CantoFish for Firefox. It will also give you Pinyun / Jyutping for the 360 doc mentioned above.

Also, using the characters you can check forvo for audio files.

I have two article that can help out:

1) [7 tips for learning Cantonese Fast](http://www.cantonesehq.com/blog/7-tips-to-learn-cantonese-fast-for-beginners)
2) [The most common words in Cantonese - how to for the suggestion above.](http://www.cantonesehq.com/blog/the-most-common-words-in-cantonese)

Hope it helps!